# Finding the Tesseract

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, thor-marvel

At the end of Thor, the tesseract falls into the bifrost, and is lost on earth. My question is, from that point, how does the tesseract wind up in a monastery in Norway?

Comment: Question is based on a false assumption.

Answer (score 7):

At the end of *Thor*, the Tesseract does not fall into the Bifrost.  The Tesseract isn't even in the film.  Loki falls into the void, and he was carrying the Casket of Ancient Winters, the powerful Frost Giant artifact he used to freeze various things during the film.

Comment: and presumably the Tesseract ended up in Norway because the Odin hid it there.

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield Nope, lost during the war with the Frost Giants, long ago.

Comment: ah, I see. Odin brought it to Earth, but it ended up in Norway all on it's own.

Comment: Doesn't it make sense that it ended up in Norway because the people of that landed worshiped them as Gods?  Remember that the Asgardians are based on Norse mythology aka Gods worshiped by Vikings in Norway.